# Is it possible to take a value from evaluation context?

Tags: haskell

I have the following sample program in Haskell:

```
fun 1 = "result1"  
fun 2 = "result2"

wrap = (\ x -> (\ _ -> fun x))

main = map wrap [1,2]
```

which yields to a

```
[test.wrap._#lambda1._#lambda2 1,test.wrap._#lambda1._#lambda2 2]
```

result.

Is it possible to get a variable (like 1 or 2) from saved context instead of storing it separately like:

```
wrap = (\ x -> (\ _ -> (fun x,x)))
```

I suppose that some metaprogramming magic is required?

Comment: It could be just me, but I don't understand the question of the "yields to a…" part of this at all.

Comment: why don't you want to *store* it?

Comment: @gspr I think I understand - Nefailus wants to get pack at the 1 from `wrap 1` just from the closure without storing it as a  additional value - the question is: why?

Comment: I do not completely understand the question, but I fear doing this requires violating referential transparency. Hence, if there is a way, it has to exploit quite low-level and unsafe stuff.

Comment: @Nefailus can you add some more on what you are trying to do here? Maybe we can show you a (better) way without *hacking*

Comment: @Nefailus then better think no it's not possible - think about it: if you would do this, than you had a function `:: String -> Int` that gives for some "result1" `1` and for others bottom (the ones comming from `wrap 1 x` vs just "result1") - but Haskell is suppost to be pure or *referential transparent* as chi put it

Comment: @Carsten König I need to distinct functions returning the same type (similar to fun x in this artificial example) at some point of the program, i.e. do one thing if i got fun 1 closure (or 3, 4 for example) , and other if got fun 2 closure (or 5, 6 as example).

Comment: @Nefailus then make it part of the return `wrap x = (x, \ _ -> fun x)` you still can get your closure with `snd` but also `x` with `fst` as well (for a real example you might use ADTs instead I guess)

Comment: Yes, the preferred way is how @CarstenKönig has demonstrated.  Don't try to "break into" a function closure, instead pass the data you need directly.  It isn't difficult to work with tuples in Haskell, particularly 2-tuples, so there is no need to try to make it more complicated than it has to be.  Remember, everything you write in Haskell is all about the data structures you use, so using the correct one is crucial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell attempts to ensure that abstractions don't break. Prime among these is the "function" abstraction. Here is the entire interface:

```
        f :: a -> b          x :: a          f ~> (\q -> E)          x ~> a
        ---------------------------          ------------------------------
                 f x :: b                             f x ~> E[q\a]
```

where `~>` means "evaluates to".

The point being that the only thing you can (morally) do to functions is apply values to them. You cannot achieve anything which needs more leverage on functions than that. Metaprogramming and the like can be used to achieve things syntactically outside of this box---in other words, you can get more leverage on not functions but instead *syntax* which results in functions, but at the end of the day you won't have much else to go on.

Ultimately, you can probably achieve what you want, but perhaps something like `(\a -> (fun a, a))` is genuinely the best way to go about it. Oftentimes things in Haskell are more explicit than you may initially expect.